# Histogram with Spark Dataframe in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to generate a histogram dataframe with Spark 2.1 in Java from a `Dataset<Row>` table?

Comment: There is a method in `JavaDoubleRDD` but I couldn't use it.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that you want to plot a histogram of your Dataset?

Comment: The final goal is this but, obviously, I won't plot with Spark. I just want to generate the frequencies of each bid somehow.

Comment: the method that I was talking about is `<double[],long[]> histogram(int bucketCount)` from `JavaDoubleRDD`

Comment: I'd suggest using pyspark instead of the Java API for this if at all possible since pyspark dataframe has a toPandas() method that converts it to a Pandas dataframe and thus you can use all the available pandas plotting methods, including pandas.DataFrame.hist. But with Java I'm assuming you're trying to convert the dataset to rdd using javaRDD() and then using histogram, what troubles are you having specifically?

Comment: I need to use Java. The problem is that I couldn't cast to `JavaDoubleRDD`.

Comment: Use JavaRDD.mapToDouble and write a mapper that extracts the value you're interested in from the row. These are old examples but might be of help - http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaDoubleRDD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149616/discussion-between-raphael-sampaio-and-oh54).

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the Dataset into JavaRDD where Datatype can be Integer, Double etc. using toJavaRDD().map() function.
2. Again Convert the JavaRDD to JavaDoubleRDD using mapToDouble function.
3. Then you can apply histogram(int bucketcount) to get the histogram of the data.

Example :
I got a table in spark with table name as 'nation' having column as 'n_nationkey' which is Integer then this is how I did it:

```
String query = "select n_nationkey from nation" ;
Dataset<Row> df = spark.sql(query);
JavaRDD<Integer> jdf = df.toJavaRDD().map(row -> row.getInt(0));
JavaDoubleRDD example = jdf.mapToDouble(y -> y);
Tuple2<double[], long[]> resultsnew = example.histogram(5);
```

In case the column have a double type, you simply replace some things as :

```
JavaRDD<Double> jdf = df.toJavaRDD().map(row -> row.getDouble(0));
JavaDoubleRDD example = jdf.mapToDouble(y -> y);
Tuple2<double[], long[]> resultsnew = example.histogram(5);
```